# How to open only camera and crop using theartofdev in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, camera, startactivityforresult

how to open only camera and crop using theartofdev dependency .I am using theartofdev dependency 2.7.+ .

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 //Declare in Manifest file
   <activity
        android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />


// Declare global variable
  Uri mCropImageUri;

// write below line on the button click 
CropImage.startPickImageActivity(this);


// then result will received inside onActivityResult() method 
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    getImageCallback(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}


  public void getImageCallback(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CropImage.PICK_IMAGE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri imageUri = CropImage.getPickImageResultUri(this, data);
        // For API >= 23 we need to check specifically that we have permissions to read external storage.
        if (CropImage.isReadExternalStoragePermissionsRequired(this, imageUri)) {
            // request permissions and handle the result in onRequestPermissionsResult()
            mCropImageUri = imageUri;
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, CropImage.PICK_IMAGE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            // no permissions required or already grunted, can start crop image activity
            startCropImageActivity(imageUri);
        }
    }
    else if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            profileImage.setImageURI(resultUri);

        }
    }
}

 private void startCropImageActivity(Uri imageUri) {
    CropImage.activity(imageUri).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.OVAL).start(this);
}
```

Comment: i am trying this already solution,this is not my solution and question .my question is that only open camera and crop image using theartofdev. no open chooser file only open camera allow ...please anyone help